# Why does my SVG image fade in when the page loads?

Tags: reactjs, svg, gatsby, gatsby-image

I added a GitHub icon in SVG format on my homepage. Link [here](https://0xnike.me/).

And whenever the page loads, the SVG image would "fade-in".

I used the StaticImage component from gatsby-plugin-image, and the .svg file is stored locally. Also, note that I have used css filter to invert the color of the .svg file since I'm using a dark background.

```
<StaticImage alt="GitHub" src="../images/github-brands.svg" className={layoutStyles.icon}/>
```

**How can I get rid of the "fade-in" effect? Or at least make it transparent?**

Comment: Stop using gatsby-plugin-image I guess: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/30699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [`placeholder` property](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#image-options), which by default is set as blurred. You can change it easily by:

```
<StaticImage 
   alt="GitHub" 
   src="../images/github-brands.svg" 
   className={layoutStyles.icon}
   placeholder="none"
 />
```

It can take the following values:

- `dominantColor`
- `tracedSVG`
- `blurred`
- `none`